# Getting scrollbar to work with absolute positioning on

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollbar

Hello I'm trying to make a game and a basic thing I want to do is add a JTextArea with a scrollbars. This is my code:

```
package TestStuff;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JTextAreaTest extends JFrame
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          new JTextAreaTest();
     }

     public JTextAreaTest()
     {
          this.setSize(1500, 600);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(
               JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          this.setLocation(450, 175);
          this.setExtendedState(JFrame.
MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
          this.setTitle("Game Display Test");

          panel1 = new JPanel(null);

          final JTextArea gameDisplay = new JTextArea(
               500, 300);
          gameDisplay.setBounds(424, 300, 500, 300);
          gameDisplay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

          Font font = new Font ("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 
              14);
          gameDisplay.setFont(font);
          gameDisplay.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

          final JScrollPane displayScroll = new JScrollPane(
               gameDisplay);
          displayScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
               JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_
                    NEEDED);
          displayScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
               JScrollPane.  
               VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

          panel1.add(gameDisplay);
          panel1.add(displayScroll);

          setContentPane(panel1);

          this.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

Everything workable fine when I run it, but when the text gets out of the bounds of the JTextArea, the scrollbars never appear! And yes, I know I'm using absolute positioning (no layout) and that's bad but I need it for other reasons in my game. Thanks in advance! (Also I can't connect to this site for some reason on my computer but I've used you guys before and you're awesome, so I have to type this on my phone. Sorry if the layout of the question gets screwed up, it the phone :P)

Comment: Yeah.... All the places where its spaced I didn't space. Lol I'm not THAT messy of a coder.

Comment: don't do any manual sizing/locating ever - that's the exclusive task of a LayoutManager which you can use **ALWAYS** (simply find or implement one that suits your needs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call...

```
panel1.add(gameDisplay);
panel1.add(displayScroll);
```

You are effectively removing the `gameDisplay` from `displayScroll`, as a component can only have one parent.

The fact that it works as it does comes down to the fact that you are playing around with the position and size of the `gameDisplay` panel instead of the `displayScroll`, which you should be...

Use

```
panel1.add(displayScroll);
```

Instead, but make sure you size and position ONLY the `displayScroll`, as `displayScroll` will take care of the `gameDisplay`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution was **setPreferredSize** on the component inside the scrollbar. I was trying to absolute position things inside the scrollbars. Luckily I knew exactly what the size should be. Maybe this is a special case.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setPreferredSize(PUT SIZE HERE);
panel.setLayout(null);
final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
```